# Slow down UIView animation within Animation

Tags: ios, animation, uiview

i have simple UIView animation block which animates the origin of 2 views. I have a Button on a special position placed on a mapview view. so when i'd like to animate the center of the map and move the pin with the map, the map moves faster than the button. Is there a way, to speed up the animation of the button or to slow down the animation of the map? At the moment it looks like the map moves and the button jumps to his end position.

```
CGPoint newCenter = mapView.center;
newCenter.x -= 1;
newCenter.y -= (button.frame.size.height/2)


[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn animations:^{

     CGPoint screenPoint = fakePin.frame.origin;
     screenPoint.x -= 5;
     screenPoint.y += button.frame.size.height-4;

     mapView.mapCoord = [mapView.map convertPoint:screenPoint toCoordinateFromView:self.view];
    self.mapView.map.centerCoordinate = mapView.mapCoord;
     [button setCenter:newCenter];
}];
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: What is your `mapCoord` and what class is your `button`?

Answer (score 1):

Why not show the button as an annotation? Then it would move along the map.

Still, try to animate the property frame on the button instead of center. You'll need to do the calculations on your own but I think that may be the problem.

Comment: i cant show it as annotation because i have to much customizations which are not supported by annotations. Calculating itself wasn't fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

i just figured out, that the Problem was that my setCenter: was called without animating, somehow it worked with the Google Maps in ios5 (animating itself but not in ios6=

No it works!!

Comment: I can't find anything in the documentation stating that it's deprecated but maybe I'm just blind.

Comment: sorry it was my fault in writing the right solution, you're not blind ;)